# Prometheus To Scrape Specific Pod

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator

I have a specific use-case in which i have to scrape a specific pod by one prometheus deployment and rest of all pods in the kubernetes cluster by second prometheus deployment.

The issuing I am facing is that I am unable to limit scraping by the second prometheus deployment that will scrape all except one pod so that this specific pod stats are not collected.

I have tried drop using following config but it didn't work

```
    - job_name: drop-pod
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: pod
      relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_app]
        action: drop
        regex: dropstats
```

Instead of dropping this config creates a new set of metrics along with the original.

The other option is to force prometheus to not scrape a pod; but i can't find a way (so far) to do that.

Does anyone has any idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to this one, posting it for anyone who might face the issue

This was due to the fact the other jobs were collecting and saving all the stats and that's why there were duplicates.